# Removing cached Users

Tags: user-profile

Last month I changed the domain of my SP 2010 portal.

I synchronized the profiles and changed the users and reassigned the permissions, also I removed old user profiles.

However inside the lists (ex. task list) when I want to select a user to assign a task, old users are seen too.

What I mean is that my new users should look like `Y\john.doe` but I also can select `X\john.doe` (`X` is my old and removed domain name).

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Have you used `Move-SPUser` after changing domain?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, they aren't cached users. They are stored in the User Info List on the Site Collections.

This is what Move-SPUser is for: `Move-SPUser -Identity "OldDomain\Bob" -NewAlias "NewDomain\Bob"`. You can enumerate your user profiles and do this or enumerate the Site Collection User Info List. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx